# Cache issue using pdf.js with Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, pdf.js

I'm working on a C# / ASP.NET flipbook project using pdf.js.
When I launch my application having an empty cache in Chrome, I load once my pdf file and everything is fine, but when I refresh the page without clearing it, the pdf is entirely downloaded 5 times, so the size goes from 7,5Mo to 37,5Mo.

I checked with IE 11, Edge, and FireFox, and I don't have issues with them.
I have already tried to disable the cache following [these instructions](http://cristian.sulea.net/blog.php?p=2014-01-14-disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags), but it didn't solve my problem.

This is where I call my file :

```
function loadBook() {
    PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
    PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../Scripts/pdf.worker.js';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var file = "http://localhost:51790/pdf/newspaper.pdf";

        PDFJS.getDocument(file).then(function getPdf(pdf) {
            var pagesNumber = pdf.numPages;

            //Adding canvas to the html
            for (var i = 1; i <= pagesNumber; i++) {
                $('.flipbook').html($('.flipbook').html() + '<div><canvas id="page' + i + '"></canvas></div>');
            }

            //Adding and rendering pages
            for (var i = 1; i <= pagesNumber; i++) {
                renderPage(i, document.getElementById('page' + i), pdf);
            }

            //Creating flipbook
            loadJournal();
        });
    })
}
```

And this is my function for the render :

```
function renderPage(numero, pageElement, pdf) {
    pdf.getPage(numero).then(function (page) {
        var scale = 1;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        pageElement.width = viewport.width;
        pageElement.height = viewport.height;

        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: pageElement.getContext('2d'),
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
}
```

I'd like to understand why it react like this.

Comment: While it may be apparently immaterial due to proper behavior under the other browsers, adding a code snippet showing what you're doing could help illuminate the situation.

Comment: it is also matter if pdf is served as a static resource or via script. PDF.js is using range requests to request only needed data and if your script is claiming it can handle HTTP range requests, the viewer can requests portions of data several times.

Comment: does your script reside inside .flipbook ?

Comment: No it doesn't. I put all my js functions in a .js file and I call the function from my cshtml file.

Comment: does your sample work fine without asp.net (just static html page)?

Comment: Indeed, it works like a charm using only html ! However, I don't really know how I could serve it statically.
I tried to follow the instructions of [this doc](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html#serving-static-files), but I didn't succeed in getting something working.